# AVCC source usage

Tags: current-source, proteus, multisim

I want to understand how the Arbitrary Voltage Controlled Current source (AVCCS) works. In Proteus, when I tried to simulate my circuit, it has some kind of a A,B formula for the source. But when I tried using it in multisim, there is something called a G for a value. How do you use this power source. For instance, if I want to simulate a solar cell, which can be seen as a voltage controlled current source,how can I use the AVCC source?

Comment: What does the Proteus manual say about this AVCCS? Ditto for the Multisim manual.

Comment: Neither of them are very helpful

Answer (score 1):

I don't know anything about Proteus or Multisim.  But stop and actually *think* about it.

These simulators apparently include "Arbitrary Voltage Controller Current Source" elements.  That pretty much says it all.  The output will be a current, and the value of that current is controlled by a input voltage.  The predominant remaining question is then how much change in voltage causes how much change in current.  In other words, there will be a constant in units of A/V.

Note that A/V = 1/Ω.  This is sometimes called units of mhos, which is "Ohm" spelled backwards.  Often the letter g is used for transconductance, which is also a unit of current/voltage, often expressed in mhos.

This is all pretty much how it has to work.  The syntax details will be unique to each particular software.  Of course this should all be spelled out clearly in the manual for each program.

So this answer, like way too many here, comes down to **READ THE MANUAL** already!

Comment: "READ THE MANUAL" - normally this would be good advice, but Multisim's '[manual](http://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/375482A-01/multisim/voltagecontrolledcurrentsourcedevice/#wp467114)' sucks. The entry for Voltage Controlled Current Source says "syntax: Gxxx o_node_p o_node_n c_node0_p c_node0_n gain... gain: voltage gain". How can it have 'voltage gain' when the output is a current?

Comment: I saw a solar panel circuit simulation in Proteus using the AVCCS  source, only the default equation 1.0*V(A,B) had  been changed slightly to (V(B))*1.23-3.373e-8*(exp(0.8309219*V(A))-1). Now I don't know what any of these variables or numbers are, or what they stand for. I tried to find out, but couldn't. The manual, in this case, doesn't actually help me.